# R shiny filter data based on user input and update the plot

Tags: r, shiny

I have an shiny application where I am filtering data based on 3 user inputs (dropdown, date and checkbox). How do we update the plot based on user selection. Example, do not show the plot when no checkbox is selected. Also how to color the plot based on checkbox selection.Also is there a way to plot all the data as default screen with examiner in x-axis and totals in y axis

```
mydata<-structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 11L, 19L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L), .Label = c("DB-1", 
"DB-11", "DB-12", "DB-13", "DB-14", "DB-15", "DB-16", "DB-17", 
"DB-18", "DB-19", "DB-2", "DB-20", "DB-23", "DB-25", "DB-26", 
"DB-27", "DB-28", "DB-29", "DB-3", "DB-30", "DB-31", "DB-32", 
"DB-34", "DB-35", "DB-36", "DB-37", "DB-4", "DB-5", "DB-6", "DB-7", 
"DB-9"), class = "factor"), examiner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Alex", 
"Jhon", "Kim", "Maymoon", "Mike"), class = "factor"), Relationship = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("father", 
"mother", "self", "sibling"), class = "factor"), application_date = structure(c(10L, 
6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 15L, 20L, 2L, 20L, 3L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 
8L, 10L, 5L, 20L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 1L, 16L, 19L, 9L, 
18L, 21L, 4L), .Label = c("1/10/19", "1/15/19", "11/13/18", "11/15/18", 
"11/20/18", "11/27/18", "11/28/18", "11/30/18", "12/20/18", "12/4/18", 
"12/6/18", "12/7/18", "2/14/19", "2/25/19", "2/26/19", "3/12/19", 
"3/14/19", "3/21/19", "3/22/19", "4/3/19", "4/5/19"), class = "factor"), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
    stage1_date = structure(c(8L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 
    13L, 11L, 13L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 17L, 12L, 
    1L, 14L, 9L, 5L, 16L, 15L, 4L, 16L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
    "1/10/19 21:40", "1/10/19 21:45", "1/17/19 19:26", "1/31/19 20:25", 
    "1/9/19 19:50", "1/9/20 14:50", "2/21/19 21:15", "2/6/19 20:36", 
    "3/15/19 16:50", "3/21/19 18:21", "3/4/19 16:30", "4/26/19 19:20", 
    "4/8/19 12:40", "4/8/19 12:41", "5/1/19 18:05", "7/30/19 15:10"
    ), class = "factor"), stage2_date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "5/11/21 17:37", "5/11/21 17:42", "5/11/21 17:50", "5/11/21 17:52", 
    "5/14/21 16:07", "5/15/21 16:07", "5/16/21 16:07", "5/21/21 17:46", 
    "5/21/21 17:47"), class = "factor"), status_stage1_2019 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L
    ), status_stage1_2020 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), status_stage1_2021 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), status_stage1_2022 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), status_stage2_2020 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), status_stage2_2021 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), status_stage2_2022 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31L))
```

My code

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    
    req(input$examiner)
   
    mydata %>%
      dplyr::filter(
        examiner %in% input$examiner ,
if_any(matches(str_c('status_', tolower(input$stage))), ~ 
                 .x ==1),
        stage1_date >= input$daterange[1] &
          stage1_date <= input$daterange[2]
      ) %>%
      group_by(Relationship) %>% summarize(Total = n())
    
  })
output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have chosen ", input$examiner)
  }) 
  #Plot 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(data())
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes( y = Total, x = Relationship))
    g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
  })
}
ui <- basicPage(
  titlePanel("My Dashboard"),
  helpText("Shows my data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "examiner",
                label = h5("Select examiner"),
                choices = c(as.character(mydata$examiner))
    ),
    dateRangeInput("daterange",
                   h5("SelectDates"),
                   format="yyyy-mm-dd",
                   start = "2001-01-01"
    ),
    checkboxGroupInput("stage",
                  h5("Select stage"),
                  choices = c("Stage1","Stage2"),
                  selected = c("Stage1","Stage2")
                  )
    ),
  
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("selected_var"),
    plotOutput("plot")
    
  )
)
```

Comment: when both 'Stage1', 'Stage2' are selected, do you need the `filter`?

Comment: Well I don't. I only need it when I de-select. So if I want to plot only stage1 data then i would need filter.

Comment: In your previous post, I updated the code.  When you deselect all, it doesn't show any plot.  If you select both, I am not sure what it should return

Comment: Regarding coloring the plots, I am guessing that you may want to reshape the data to long format first

Comment: If I select both then data from both stages should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the class of `stage1_date` -> it is factor. Use `lubridate`s `ymd_hm` function to transform it to date. Then your code will work!

Just add this line of code straight after `my_data %>%`:

```
library(lubridate)
....
....

    mydata %>%
      mutate(stage1_date = mdy_hm(as.character(stage1_date))) %>%
....
....
```

Here is the complete code with working app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


mydata<-structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 11L, 19L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L), .Label = c("DB-1", 
"DB-11", "DB-12", "DB-13", "DB-14", "DB-15", "DB-16", "DB-17", 
"DB-18", "DB-19", "DB-2", "DB-20", "DB-23", "DB-25", "DB-26", 
"DB-27", "DB-28", "DB-29", "DB-3", "DB-30", "DB-31", "DB-32", 
"DB-34", "DB-35", "DB-36", "DB-37", "DB-4", "DB-5", "DB-6", "DB-7", 
"DB-9"), class = "factor"), examiner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Alex", 
"Jhon", "Kim", "Maymoon", "Mike"), class = "factor"), Relationship = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("father", 
"mother", "self", "sibling"), class = "factor"), application_date = structure(c(10L, 
6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 15L, 20L, 2L, 20L, 3L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 
8L, 10L, 5L, 20L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 1L, 16L, 19L, 9L, 
18L, 21L, 4L), .Label = c("1/10/19", "1/15/19", "11/13/18", "11/15/18", 
"11/20/18", "11/27/18", "11/28/18", "11/30/18", "12/20/18", "12/4/18", 
"12/6/18", "12/7/18", "2/14/19", "2/25/19", "2/26/19", "3/12/19", 
"3/14/19", "3/21/19", "3/22/19", "4/3/19", "4/5/19"), class = "factor"), 
gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
stage1_date = structure(c(8L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 
13L, 11L, 13L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 17L, 12L, 
1L, 14L, 9L, 5L, 16L, 15L, 4L, 16L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
"1/10/19 21:40", "1/10/19 21:45", "1/17/19 19:26", "1/31/19 20:25", 
"1/9/19 19:50", "1/9/20 14:50", "2/21/19 21:15", "2/6/19 20:36", 
"3/15/19 16:50", "3/21/19 18:21", "3/4/19 16:30", "4/26/19 19:20", 
"4/8/19 12:40", "4/8/19 12:41", "5/1/19 18:05", "7/30/19 15:10"
), class = "factor"), stage2_date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"5/11/21 17:37", "5/11/21 17:42", "5/11/21 17:50", "5/11/21 17:52", 
"5/14/21 16:07", "5/15/21 16:07", "5/16/21 16:07", "5/21/21 17:46", 
"5/21/21 17:47"), class = "factor"), status_stage1_2019 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L
), status_stage1_2020 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), status_stage1_2021 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), status_stage1_2022 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), status_stage2_2020 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), status_stage2_2021 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), status_stage2_2022 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31L))

 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    
    req(input$examiner)
    
    mydata %>%
      mutate(stage1_date = mdy_hm(as.character(stage1_date))) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(
        examiner %in% input$examiner ,
        if_any(matches(str_c('status_', tolower(input$stage))), ~ 
                 .x ==1),
        stage1_date >= input$daterange[1] &
          stage1_date <= input$daterange[2]
      ) %>%
      group_by(Relationship) %>% summarize(Total = n())
    
  })
  output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have chosen ", input$examiner)
  }) 
  #Plot 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(data())
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes( y = Total, x = Relationship))
    g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
    #browser()
  })
 # browser()
}
ui <- basicPage(
  titlePanel("My Dashboard"),
  helpText("Shows my data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "examiner",
                label = h5("Select examiner"),
                choices = c(as.character(mydata$examiner))
    ),
    dateRangeInput("daterange",
                   h5("SelectDates"),
                   format="yyyy-mm-dd",
                   start = "2001-01-01"
    ),
    checkboxGroupInput("stage",
                       h5("Select stage"),
                       choices = c("Stage1","Stage2"),
                       selected = c("Stage1","Stage2")
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("selected_var"),
    plotOutput("plot")
    
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: i am doing this when reading the data mydata$stage1_date <- as.Date(
  mydata$stage1_date,
  format = "%Y-%m-%d",
  optional=FALSE)

Comment: With this code you provide you get NA in mydata$stage1_date -> `mydata$stage1_date
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`. This is because mydata$stage has hours and minutes.